# "grep -r foo *" vs "grep -r foo ."

Tags: grep, wildcards

When using grep -r you could search in all files with either * or .
and it seems to return the same thing but is it really the same?

Let's say I search for "foo", then I could write

```
grep -r foo *
```

or

```
grep -r foo .
```

Would anyone try to explain the difference between .  and *?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`grep -r foo *` doesn't look for matches in hidden files or directories,
also `*` is expanded by the shell so you might end up with an *Argument list too long* error when there are a lot of entries in the current directory, or some other errors or misbehaviour if the name of some of the files or directories starts with a dash character.

Invocation `grep -r foo .` doesn't have the above flaws

*Updated:*

Another difference: grep's man page (@fedora17) says:

```
-r, --recursive
    Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they
    are on  the  command  line.  ...
```

There will be also a difference when you execute this command in an empty directory:

```
$ grep -r foo *; echo $?
grep: *: No such file or directory
2
$ grep -r foo .; echo $?
1
$
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use asterisk, you cannot match files in directories whose name start with a dot, like `.cache`.

*Update:*

This is because the `*` is expanded by the shell before calling `grep`, so it receive a list of names instead of a single directory name (for the current `.`).
The way shell expand the pattern may be customized with shell parameter (as for `nullglob`, `nocaseglob` or other `bash` options) or be environment variables (like `LANG` or `LC_ALL`)